# How to create a URL shortner (with python) without importing bittly or other stuff

Tags: python, web, url, https

So I recently became interested into knowing how to create a URL shortener without using bittly or other things, but I am not very good at using python to connect with other stuff. All I know is:

- Checking to see if the URL is available ( Only to see if it has HTTP:// and unavailable characters, nothing to see if the domain is occupied or not. )

All of the other things... I need help with.

By the way, I COMPLETLY do not understand how to do that, so it would be great if you add comments to show me what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at Flask, it is a framework for building web applications (APIs, web apps, etc.).

DigitalOcean has a [nice tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-make-a-url-shortener-with-flask-and-sqlite) on this.

You can either use hashing algorithms for the custom shortened urls, or even let the user pick more readable names (like bit.ly/my-url). In this case you would be storing in a database the shortened url and the long url.